# Leaflet - Draw a Circle that fits around a Bounding Box

Tags: leaflet

In Leaflet docs, L.Circle Radius is based on meters, but how can I draw a Circle based on coordinates instead?

More specifically, I want to draw a circle that encompasses a specific bounding box

```js
const myCenter = [37, -122];
const myBoundingBox = {
  northEast: [myCenter[0]+2, myCenter[1]+2],
  southWest: [myCenter[0]-2, myCenter[1]-2]
};
const circle = L.circle(myCenter, {radius: ??}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, use map.distance function to get distance in meters between the diagonal points of the bounds

```js
const circleRadius = map.distance(myBoundingBox[northEast], myBoundingBox[southWest])/2
```

Then just create the circle normally using the radius in meters